# batch file to start when a new document is saved

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, automation, file-monitoring

okay my question is rather simple I want to create a batch file or a shell script that will start when a file is saved to the documents folder so that it can sort the file to its specified sub folder. can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

I would prefer to not have to install separate programs, and would like to keep this as a batch.

machine note: OS=Windows 7 pro

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: this code works perfect for what I needed:

```
    @echo off 
    :A
    CD "desktop\file moving test"
    tree

    move /Y 1*.* 1*
    move /Y 2*.* 2*
    move /Y 3*.* 3*
    goto A
```

Thank you to every one who answered.

Comment: is not a problem to keep the CMD window opened all day to monitor the file changes?, better you would use 3rd party apps like Directory Monitor http://www.brutaldev.com/page/Directory-Monitor.

Comment: actually I normally keep a batch file open all day. it would just be another prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make a batch file, that you use to save the file in the folder, and then run the process you need, or you set it as a windows process, and run a it every n time, to check in differences. If differences are found, then run your logic.  Somthing like the following, and compare it to the prior count. I would do it as a scheduled task, that runs your batch file.

```
@echo off
for /f %%A in ('dir ^| find "File(s)"') do set cnt=%%A
echo File count = %cnt%
```

Comment: Normally when you do a repetitive task in windows batching, it is best to do it as a "scheduled task". Sounds kind of weird saying it that way. I am a Bash man myself, but use to handle windows operations when automating a banking system this way.

Comment: Scheduled task would need to be called every minute for nice results, displaying the CMD window producing an horrible and disgusting visual effect, you better would consider to keep the CMD opened with that code, or use VSB method to run hide the batch file, or use 3rd party free apps (best solution).

Comment: my computer will not be able to perform a scheduled tasks due to the way the school has configured the image of the net-book. so is there another way to do it?

Comment: @CS_STEM Yes, please see my answer where I've posted a code which can be launched as is within task scheduler, but really I recommend to use any other alternatives not Batch/Bash. PS: Forgive my English.

Comment: @ElektroHacker another alternative will not be needed. I probably did not see your answer before I posted that comment. and thank you for answering, I'll try the code and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a loop and `timeout` (Vista and higher) or `ping` to delay for 5 minutes, and repeat the loop.

```
@echo off
:loop
  if exist *.txt (
     copy "*.txt" "d:\wherever"
  ) 
timeout 300
goto :loop
```

Comment: timeout? if that command does exist how come it is not in the help list?

Comment: @CS_STEM A drunk friday at the Microsoft cmd support team headquarters?

Comment: I am not sure about drunk, but I will look around at the support page.

Answer (score 1):

For monitoring file changes in the Documents folder you can call this `batch-file` from a previous scheduled task which you can create with `SCHTASK` command:

```
@Echo OFF

REM By Elektro H@cker

PUSHD "%USERPROFILE%\Documents"

:: Recycle past session logs
Del /Q "%TEMP%\FileList.tmp","%TEMP%\FileListNew.tmp"

:Monitor_Loop
If Exist "%TEMP%\FileList.tmp" (
    Dir /B /A-D > "%TEMP%\FileListNew.tmp"
    Echo N | Comp "%TEMP%\FileList.tmp" "%TEMP%\FileListNew.tmp" 1>NUL 2>&1 || (
        Echo File changes found on directory.
        Call :FileOp
    )

    MOVE /Y "%TEMP%\FileListNew.tmp" "%TEMP%\FileList.tmp" 1>NUL

    ) ELSE (

        Dir /B /A-D > "%TEMP%\FileList.tmp"
)

REM Ping -n 5 LOCALHOST 1>NUL
Timeout /T 5 1>NUL & REM Avoid Ping while you are in Windows 7/8.
GOTO :Monitor_Loop

:FileOp
For %%# in ("*") Do (Echo "%%~#")
GOTO:EOF
```

PS: Just add the operations that you need to perform with the new files found inside the `:FileOp` procedure.

you maybe would like to use this `VBScript` file to run the task/batch hidden:

```
' Run Hidden Process
' By Elektro H@cker

Process   = """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """"
Arguments = null

For X = 1 to WScript.Arguments.Count - 1
   Arguments = Arguments & " " & _
               """" & WScript.Arguments(X) & """"
Next

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run _
Process & " " & Arguments, 0, False

Wscript.Quit
```